# Set default tab in .js

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have this js code:

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

```
// filtering subcategories
var theFilter = $(".filter");
var containerFrame = $(theFilter).closest(".container-frame")
var filterHeight = $(".filter").children("li").first().find("a").outerHeight(true);

function addFilterHeight( addHeight, op ) {
    $(containerFrame).animate( { marginBottom: op + addHeight + "px" }, 1200);
}


$(theFilter).children("li").children("a").on( "click",  
        function() {    
            var thisChildren = $(this).siblings('.children');
            var thisChildrenDisplay = $(thisChildren).css("display");
            var activeFilter = $(this).closest('li');

            $(this).closest('.filter').find('li').removeClass('active-sub-filter');
            $(activeFilter).addClass('active-sub-filter');

            // spacing for multi-line filters
            var spacingMultiLine = ($(theFilter).height() - $(activeFilter).height() - $(this).position().top);

            if(thisChildrenDisplay == "block") { // block: already clicked

            } else if(thisChildrenDisplay == "none") { // none: first time clicked

                $(theFilter).find('.children').slideUp("fast");

                // normalize spacing
                $(theFilter).find('.children').css("marginTop", 10);
                // first level spacing                  
                addFilterHeight(60 + $(thisChildren).outerHeight(true), "");

                 //console.log($(thisChildren).outerHeight(true));

                // first level filters spacing 
                $(thisChildren).css("marginTop", "+=" + spacingMultiLine);
                // show first level children filters
                $(thisChildren).slideDown("fast");  


                // all the children filters click function
                $(this).siblings(".children").find("li").find("a").on( "click", 
                    function() {    
                        var nestedChildren = $(this).siblings('.children'); 
                        var nestedChildrenHeight = parseInt(filterHeight);// $(nestedChildren).outerHeight(true); since 1.7
                        var activeSubFilter = $(this).closest('li');

                        // remove highlight
                        $(this).closest(".children").find("li").removeClass('active-sub-filter');
                        // hide all children .children
                        $(this).closest(".children").find('.children').hide();                          
                        // add highlight
                        $(activeSubFilter).addClass('active-sub-filter');

                        if($(nestedChildren).css("display") != "block") { // first time or no children
                            if($(nestedChildren).css("display") == "none") {
                                $(nestedChildren).slideDown("fast", function() {
                                    // add spacing when first time
                                        $multiplier = $(theFilter).find('ul.children:visible').size();
                                        addFilterHeight((nestedChildrenHeight * $multiplier) + 60, "");                                     
                                });

                            } else { // no children
                                $multiplier = $(theFilter).find('ul.children:visible').size();
                                //nestedChildrenHeight = $(this).closest("ul.children").outerHeight(true); since 1.7
                                addFilterHeight((nestedChildrenHeight * $multiplier) + 60, "");
                            }
                        } else { // already clicked

                            //hide all siblings "li" children
                            $(this).closest("li").siblings("li").find("ul.children").hide();

                            $(nestedChildren).slideDown("fast", function() {
                                // add spacing when first time                                  
                                    $multiplier = $(theFilter).find('ul.children:visible').size();
                                    addFilterHeight((nestedChildrenHeight * $multiplier) + 60, "");                                     
                            });

                        }

                    }
                );

            } else { // undefined  no children
                // first level filters spacing 
                $(theFilter).find('.children').css("marginTop", 10);
                $(theFilter).find('.children').slideUp("fast");

                // set to default spacing
                addFilterHeight(60, "");
            }
        }
);              
// end filtering subcategories

// Initialize prettyPhoto
$(".portfolio a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
    theme:'pp_default', 
    autoplay_slideshow: false, 
    overlay_gallery: false, 
    show_title: false,
    counter_separator_label: '/',
    social_tools: false
});

// clone portfolio items 
var $portfolioClone = $(".portfolio").clone();

// Attempt to call Quicksand on every click event handler
$(".filter li a").click(function(e){

    // remove "current" class from currently selected filter
    $(".filter li a").removeClass("current");   

    // Get Filter type
    var $filterClass = $(this).attr("class");

    if ( $filterClass == "all" ) {
        var $filteredPortfolio = $portfolioClone.find("li");
    } else {
        var $filteredPortfolio = $portfolioClone.find("li[data-type~=" + $filterClass + "]");
    }

    //Set variable for items in a row; default is 4
    var items_in_a_row = 4;

    // Remove current class 
    $( ".filter li a" ).removeClass( "current" ); 

    // no. of columns will depend on portfolio layout for mobile, tablet or screen view
    if ( $( '#items' ).hasClass('three-columns') ) { items_in_a_row = 3 }
    else if ( $( '#items' ).hasClass('with-sidebar') ) { items_in_a_row = 3 }
    else if ( $( '#items' ).hasClass('two-columns') ) { items_in_a_row = 2 }
    else { items_in_a_row = 4 }

    var $filterType = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[0]; 
    $(this).addClass("current"); 

    if ($filterType == "all") { 
        var $filteredDataType = $portfolioClone.find("li[data-type]"); 
        var i = 1; 

        $filteredDataType.each(function() {
            var $self = $(this);
            $self.removeClass("alpha omega");

            if(i === 1) {
                $self.addClass("alpha");
            }
            else if( i === items_in_a_row ) {
                $self.addClass("omega");        

            }

            if ( i === items_in_a_row ) {
                i = 1;
            }
            else {
                i++;
            }
        });

    }
    else {
        var $filteredDataType = $portfolioClone.find("li[data-type~=" + $filterClass + "]");
        var i = 1;
        $filteredDataType.each(function() {
            var $self = $(this);
            $self.removeClass("alpha omega");

            if ( i === 1 ) {
                $self.addClass("alpha");
            }
            else if ( i === items_in_a_row ) {
                var $html = $self.html();
                $self.addClass("omega");        

            }

            if( i === items_in_a_row ) {
                i = 1;
            }
            else {
                i++;
            }
        });
    }

    // Call quicksand
    $(".portfolio").quicksand( $filteredPortfolio, { 
        duration: 800,
        easing: 'linear',
        adjustHeight: 'dynamic',
        useScaling: true,
        enhancement: function() {
            // portfolio item rounded           
            $(document).ready(function(){       
                if(jQuery().roundThis){
                        $(".portfolio-items").find('.overlay').find('img').roundThis($(this).width());                      
                }
            });



        }
    }, function(){

        //add prettyPhoto to cloned items
        $(".portfolio a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
            autoplay_slideshow: false, 
            overlay_gallery: false, 
            show_title: true
        });

        if( $filterClass != 'all'){
            jQuery('.portfolio-items ul#items li.omega').after('<li class="clearer"><div class="clear"></div></li>');
        }
        jQuery('.portfolio').css('height', 'auto');         

        //portfolio item hover function
        $('.overlay').hover(            
            function(){             
                $(this).find('img').animate({ opacity:'0.8' }, 450, 'easeInOutCubic');
                $(this).find('.icon-view').stop(true, true).animate({ opacity: '0.75' }, 10, 'swing'); //, marginTop: '-0.5em'
                $(this).find('.icon-link').stop(true, true).animate({ opacity: '0.75' }, 10, 'swing'); //, marginTop: '-0.5em'
                $(this).find('h5').animate({ opacity: '1' }, 10, 'linear');
            },function(){                   
                $(this).find('h5').animate({ opacity: '0.0' }, 300, 'linear');
                $(this).find('.icon-view').stop(true, true).animate({ opacity: '0.0' }, 10, 'swing'); //, marginTop: parentHeight
                $(this).find('.icon-link').stop(true, true).animate({ opacity: '0.0' }, 10, 'swing');//, marginTop: parentHeight                    
                $(this).find('img').animate({ opacity: '1' }, 450, 'easeInOutCubic');
            }
        );              

        $('.overlay .icon-view, .overlay .icon-link').hover(            
            function(){             
                $(this).stop(true, true).animate({ opacity: '1' }, 20);                 
            },function(){
                $(this).stop(true, true).animate({ opacity: '0.75' }, 20);  
            }
        );          

        // portfolio callback
        $( '.portfolio-content-link' ).click( function() {
            $( '#loader-img' ).css('visibility', 'visible').fadeIn(1200); 
        });

        // add click event for each item        
        $( ".portfolio-content-link" ).click( getPortfolio );   


    });


    $(this).addClass("current");

    e.preventDefault();
})
```

});

And what I want is that a **a href="#Active"** button to be the selected/active button. For this button is **li data-type="active"** content. How can I do this ?

With this java code, when I go to my page rhondascott.com/listings both tabs are shown in first time. I want to make the "Active" one as default to show when I go to my page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `click` it right after attaching the `click` event listener.

```
<a href="#Active" title="Active" class="active" data-default="true">Active</a>


$(theFilter).children("li").children("a[data-default="true"]").click();
```

right after attaching the click listener.

I've no idea where and who generates that hyperlink, that's for you to figure in the WordPress template.

Comment: Mersi mult, dar nu merge.

Comment: Looking at your website I can see there's no `ul.tabs`. So `tabs.each` iterates over an empty array.

Comment: Then what I must to do/change to make this working? And then why when I click "Active" for example show me the "Active" tab.

Comment: Well, it turns out that code has nothing to do with those "tabs". The code that handles those is here: http://rhondascott.com/wp-content/themes/morphis/js/custom.quicksand.js?ver=1.0

Comment: Sorry. Asking again, what I must change on this code custom.quicksand.js ? Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: When I replace the line 13 `$(theFilter).children("li").children("a").on( "click",` with your code `$(theFilter).children("li").children("a[data-default="true"]").click();` the Dreamweaver tell me that there is a syntax error. If you need I can show you the PHP file

Comment: I did not say replace it. You are essentially defining what should happen when the user clicks that hyperlink using a function, right? All you have to do is call that function for the right hyperlink (the "default" one) at initialization.

Comment: But for example if I want that the first "li" to be the default how can I do that?

Comment: This should work `$(theFilter).children("li").first().children("a").click();`